# Slow PostgreSQL query with (incorrect?) indexes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have an Events table with 30 million rows. The following query returns in 25 seconds

```
SELECT DISTINCT "events"."id", "calendars"."user_id" 
FROM "events" 
LEFT JOIN "calendars" ON "events"."calendar_id" = "calendars"."id" 
WHERE "events"."deleted_at" is null 
AND tstzrange('2016-04-21T12:12:36-07:00', '2016-04-21T12:22:36-07:00') @> lower(time_range) 
AND ("status" is null or (status->>'pre_processed') IS NULL)
```

`status` is a `jsonb` column with an index on `status->>'pre_processed'`. Here are the other indexes that were created on the events table. `time_range` is of type `TSTZRANGE`.

```
CREATE INDEX events_time_range_idx ON events USING gist (time_range);
CREATE INDEX events_lower_time_range_index on events(lower(time_range));
CREATE INDEX events_upper_time_range_index on events(upper(time_range));
CREATE INDEX events_calendar_id_index on events (calendar_id)
```

I'm definitely out of my comfort zone on this and am trying to reduce the query time. Here's the output of explain analyze

```
  HashAggregate  (cost=7486635.89..7486650.53 rows=1464 width=48) (actual time=26989.272..26989.306 rows=98 loops=1)
  Group Key: events.id, calendars.user_id
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..7486628.57 rows=1464 width=48) (actual time=316.110..26988.941 rows=98 loops=1)
    ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..7475629.43 rows=1464 width=50) (actual time=316.049..26985.344 rows=98 loops=1)
          Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND ((status IS NULL) OR ((status ->> 'pre_processed'::text) IS NULL)) AND ('["2016-04-21 19:12:36+00","2016-04-21 19:22:36+00")'::tstzrange @> lower(time_range)))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 31592898
    ->  Index Scan using calendars_pkey on calendars  (cost=0.42..7.50 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=1 loops=98)
          Index Cond: (events.calendar_id = (id)::text)
Planning time: 1.468 ms
Execution time: 26989.370 ms
```

And here is the explain analyze with the `events.deleted_at` part of the query removed

```
HashAggregate  (cost=7487382.57..7487398.33 rows=1576 width=48) (actual time=23880.466..23880.503 rows=115 loops=1)
  Group Key: events.id, calendars.user_id
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..7487374.69 rows=1576 width=48) (actual time=16.612..23880.114 rows=115 loops=1)
    ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..7475629.43 rows=1576 width=50) (actual time=16.576..23876.844 rows=115 loops=1)
          Filter: (((status IS NULL) OR ((status ->> 'pre_processed'::text) IS NULL)) AND ('["2016-04-21 19:12:36+00","2016-04-21 19:22:36+00")'::tstzrange @> lower(time_range)))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 31592881
    ->  Index Scan using calendars_pkey on calendars  (cost=0.42..7.44 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=115)
          Index Cond: (events.calendar_id = (id)::text)
```

Planning time: 0.372 ms
Execution time: 23880.571 ms

I added the index on the `status` column. Everything else what already there and I'm unsure how to proceed going forward. Any suggestions on how to get the query time down to a more manageable number?

Comment: The structures of the events and the calendars table would be helpfull. If you could post the explain analyze output instead of just the explain that could help too.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks. I added the explain analyze. I can add the structure later. I mentioned the fields I'm querying on are TSTZRANGE and JSONB. deleted_at is just a timestamp

Comment: Not sure you need the `@> lower(time_range)` wouldn't an "overlaps" do the same? `where ... @> time_range` - that might use the gist index on that column. Also which of the conditions removes the most of the rows? The condition on `status`, the one on `time_range` or the one on `deleted_at`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name remove the `lower` actually made the query slower. Status reduces the rows the most (many thousands)

Comment: Add an index to the calendar_id in the events table and make sure it's indexed in the calendar table.

Comment: @Harry Thanks. There is already an index on `calendar_id`. I just forgot to add it to the question. I've updated it now. It's the primary key of the calendars table also and is indexed as such.

Comment: Do you need DISTINCT on both columns? Is it faster if you remove distinct.

Comment: @Harry The query returns the same without the distinct

Comment: I worked in a place we had a similar problem, millions of data to check and everyday there was something we sort of needed from it. Not sure if it might help you but, we created a view that was updated everyday and took the data from there, so we didn't need the 25s (in this case) delay for every query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The B-tree index on `lower(time_range)` can only be used for conditions involving the `<`, `<=`, `=`, `>=` and `>` operators. The `@>` operator may rely on these internally, but as far as the planner is concerned, this range check operation is a black box, and so it can't make use of the index.

You will need to reformulate your condition in terms of the B-tree operators, i.e.:

```
lower(time_range) >= '2016-04-21T12:12:36-07:00' AND
lower(time_range) < '2016-04-21T12:22:36-07:00'
```

Comment: You're the man. 68ms with that little change. I suspected it was something to do with how I was querying on the time range but I'm pretty out of my element here. It's now using an index scan `Index Scan using events_lower_time_range_index on events  (cost=0.57..2177.94 rows=5 width=50) (actual time=0.019..0.186 rows=98 loops=1)`. It says I can award you the bounty in 2 hours. Thanks!

Comment: The first time I change the time range, it takes considerably and variably longer (10s, 30s, 16s) but all the subsequent queries on that time range are <1s. Are there other tweaks that can help avoid this or is it just how the Postgres internals work?

Comment: It's probably due to caching; the first query has to hit the disk, but subsequent queries find all of the data in RAM. Increasing the cache size (by raising [`shared_buffers`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS) and/or adding more RAM) might help somewhat, but there's no silver bullet.

Comment: Other than that, you could try to reduce the amount of data which the query needs to consider, by creating either a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) or a [table partition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) based on your query's `status` and `deleted_at` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

So add an index for `events.deleted_at` to get rid of the nasty sequential scan.  What does it look like after that?

Comment: It takes a while to add an index to this table, so in the mean time I just removed the `WHERE "events"."deleted_at" is null ` and the query still returned in the same amount of time. Posted the explain analyze output of that. Looks like the sequential scan is still running